# How to create a link component that displays an image on hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a react component that behaves much like [wikipedia's page preview](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2018/04/18/how-we-designed-page-previews-for-wikipedia/) but without the text. When hovering over the link, I'd like the image to display either above or below the text.

I've made a `ImgCard` component that displays an `a` link and, while hovering, displays the image. I get this sense that I might be over-engineering the component itself, so if that's the case, please feel free to simplify it. In the example below, I'm using [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/).

Issues so far:

- The image won't render if there is not enough space. You can see an example of this by hovering over the `spongebob 5` link. In this case, it would be nice if it was smart enough to know that it needs to appear above the text.
- It seems the images are always appearing to the left.

What's the best way to handle this?

```js
const {useState} = React;

function ImgCard({ src, alt, text }) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <a
        href={src}
        className="text-blue-600 visited:text-purple-600"
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
      >
        {text}
      </a>
      {isShown && (
        <img
          className="max-w-xs rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg absolute"
          src={src}
          alt={alt}
        />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Page(){
  return(
    <div className="max-w-xl mx-auto px-8">
    <h1 className="text-2xl text-gray-900 font-semibold">The Best Lorem Ever
    </h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <ImgCard text="spongebob 1" src="https://i.imgur.com/TYHtyCe.png" />. Nam imperdiet magna quis consectetur gravida. Nam maximus consectetur rhoncus. Nulla facilisi. Ut convallis risus at odio euismod, <ImgCard text="spongebob 2" src="https://i.imgur.com/tnOglmb.png" /> sodales tincidunt augue bibendum. Sed hendrerit arcu ut ipsum mattis, id eleifend sem dictum. Etiam finibus elementum vulputate. Suspendisse nec sem ex.
        </p>
        <p>
 <ImgCard text="spongebob 3" src="https://i.imgur.com/m8oAgs8.jpg" /> in porttitor sapien, ac egestas libero. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sed tempus ligula. Praesent efficitur aliquam varius. Proin ex libero, hendrerit sit amet massa ac, mollis semper nulla. Vestibulum ultrices rhoncus metus, vel pellentesque erat iaculis in. Duis ut ligula in lacus volutpat mattis maximus nec nunc. Sed euismod tortor non mauris porta fringilla. Cras aliquam quis odio sit amet dapibus. In et eros venenatis, interdum dui at, accumsan mauris. Proin nec pulvinar leo. Duis in turpis vel mi cursus venenatis. Sed dapibus elit leo, sit amet ornare nisi commodo
        </p>
        <p>
<ImgCard text="spongebob 4" src="https://i.imgur.com/vYCijFL.jpg"  /> Mauris vitae iaculis turpis, nec sodales diam. Duis euismod, velit tincidunt laoreet porta, sem nulla lobortis tellus, non fringilla ipsum mauris et massa. Pellentesque vel ante sem. Integer ut mauris aliquet dolor auctor porttitor ut eget sem. Vestibulum egestas tellus ut mi dignissim fringilla. Phasellus ut gravida quam, nec rutrum lectus. Fusce ut volutpat diam, vitae dignissim enim. Vivamus dapibus nunc eu neque porta, ut luctus est venenatis. Suspendisse eu neque eget lorem feugiat pharetra auctor auctor augue. Mauris malesuada id leo sit amet maximus. Morbi egestas placerat arcu at posuere. Nam hendrerit dignissim odio, quis gravida magna pulvinar sed. Ut tincidunt elit semper eleifend rhoncus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum malesuada luctus rutrum. <ImgCard text="spongebob 5" src="https://i.imgur.com/LthzuJn.jpg"  />
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Page />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi, just a friendly reminder: the last `<ImgCard>` has the following attribute `src="hhttps://i.imgur.com/LthzuJn.jpg"`. As you can see it has a double `h` that is why the last element won't render: it can't find the image. Remove one `h` and you are already one step closer!

Comment: Ah, thanks for that find! I fixed the typo, but I am still curious about having the image appear directly above or below the corresponding text. The example width is very narrow so its hard to tell, but the images always appear on the left side of the container. I'm no CSS guru but I am sure my desired effect is possible. Thanks again!

Comment: I see! I'm working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect that you found the typo. The best approach to solve your second problem is to create a container with a [relative positioning](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position/) to the `Link` element. I made a codesandbox to supply an example. You might want to improve your code, I am not really familiar with `TailwindCSS`. https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-image-popup-lvcei
Take in consideration that the image might overflow the screen borders. To solve this you can calculate the distance between `Screen Border` and `Link`. Based on the Image width and the calculated space you change the Image className to `left-0` or `right-0`

Comment: That did the trick! Regarding the screen overflow, I'll need to get crafty with that one since it doesn't look good on smaller screens. Also, in the example, the last image 'pushes' the page length down to make room for itself. It would be great if the component knew that it needs to appear above the text, instead of below, in this case. But that is likely out of the scope of pure CSS. Thanks again, I'll be giving you the bounty as soon as the time limit is up!

Answer (score 1):

first of all, thanks for the challenge as I'm not that familiar with react. However I reckon I have a proper solution.

As I have copied your code I won't explain that part. Basically I have added a function that checks `onMouseOver` whether the `<a>` is in the top or bottom of the screen. Then it sets the state of `position` accordingly and then the `ImgCard` is rendered accordingly as well.

```js
const {useState, useRef, useEffect} = React;

function ImgCard({ src, alt, text }) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  //create an identifier for each element
  const inputRef = useRef();
  //set the default state for the position of an image
  const [position, setPosition] = useState("image-below");
  const [disOffCenter, setDisOffCenter] = useState(6.67);

  //check the position of the <a> tag relative to the current viewport
  const positionImg = function() {
    //"Spongebob 1" has a length of ~100px
    //I made a calculated guess that 1rem = 15px thus 100px = 6.67 rem
    //The image with = max-w-xs or 20 rem
    //The image is centered when it is (20 - 6.6) / 2 = -6.665
    let textWidth = inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width / 15;
    let distanceOffCenter = (20 - textWidth) / 2;
    setDisOffCenter(distanceOffCenter);
    
    if((window.innerHeight / 2) > inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().y) {
       //if the <a> element is on the lower half of the screen: show the image above it
       setPosition("image-above");
    } else {
      //if the <a> element is on the top half of the screen: show the image below it
      setPosition("image-below");
    }
  
  }
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <a
        href={src}
        className="text-blue-600 visited:text-purple-600 relative"
        onMouseEnter={() => {setIsShown(true); positionImg();}}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
        ref={inputRef}
      >
        {text},
        {isShown && (
        <img
          className={"max-w-xs rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg absolute " + position}
          style={{"margin-left" : "-" + disOffCenter + "rem"}}
          src={src}
          alt={alt}
        />
      )}
      </a>
      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Page(){
  return(
    <div className="max-w-xl mx-auto px-8">
    <h1 className="text-2xl text-gray-900 font-semibold">The Best Lorem Ever
    </h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <ImgCard text="spongebob 1" src="https://i.imgur.com/TYHtyCe.png" />. Nam imperdiet magna quis consectetur gravida. Nam maximus consectetur rhoncus. Nulla facilisi. Ut convallis risus at odio euismod, <ImgCard text="spongebob 2" src="https://i.imgur.com/tnOglmb.png" /> sodales tincidunt augue bibendum. Sed hendrerit arcu ut ipsum mattis, id eleifend sem dictum. Etiam finibus elementum vulputate. Suspendisse nec sem ex.
        </p>
        <p>
 <ImgCard text="spongebob 3" src="https://i.imgur.com/m8oAgs8.jpg" /> in porttitor sapien, ac egestas libero. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sed tempus ligula. Praesent efficitur aliquam varius. Proin ex libero, hendrerit sit amet massa ac, mollis semper nulla. Vestibulum ultrices rhoncus metus, vel pellentesque erat iaculis in. Duis ut ligula in lacus volutpat mattis maximus nec nunc. Sed euismod tortor non mauris porta fringilla. Cras aliquam quis odio sit amet dapibus. In et eros venenatis, interdum dui at, accumsan mauris. Proin nec pulvinar leo. Duis in turpis vel mi cursus venenatis. Sed dapibus elit leo, sit amet ornare nisi commodo
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
<ImgCard text="spon" src="https://i.imgur.com/vYCijFL.jpg"  /> - small text to test variable text widths. Mauris vitae iaculis turpis, nec sodales diam. Duis euismod, velit tincidunt laoreet porta, sem nulla lobortis tellus, non fringilla ipsum mauris et massa. Pellentesque vel ante sem. Integer ut mauris aliquet dolor auctor porttitor ut eget sem. Vestibulum egestas tellus ut mi dignissim fringilla. Phasellus ut gravida quam, nec rutrum lectus. Fusce ut volutpat diam, vitae dignissim enim. Vivamus dapibus nunc eu neque porta, ut luctus est venenatis. Suspendisse eu neque eget lorem feugiat pharetra auctor auctor augue. Mauris malesuada id leo sit amet maximus. Morbi egestas placerat arcu at posuere. Nam hendrerit dignissim odio, quis gravida magna pulvinar sed. Ut tincidunt elit semper eleifend rhoncus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum malesuada luctus rutrum. <ImgCard text="spongebob 5" src="https://i.imgur.com/LthzuJn.jpg"  />
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Page />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
/*The image is 20px above the element*/
.image-above {
  top: 1.5rem;
}

/*The image is 20px below the element*/
.image-below {
  bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.image-above, .image-below {
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope this helps! If not, please comment

#### Edit

I've now added the code so that the image will always be centered above or below the text inside of the `<a>`-tags. It's method is best described by the comments I have added in the code:

> "Spongebob 1" has a length of `~100px`
>
> I made a calculated guess that `1rem` = `15px` thus `100px` = `6.67rem`
>
> The image width is `max-w-xs` or `20rem`
>
> The image is centered when it is `(20 - 6.6) / 2` = `6.665`
>
> It is `-6.665rem` because the images are normally aligned to the left, thus you have to make them even more left, if that makes sense.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This certainly helped a lot and I greatly appreciate your detailed response! Do you think there would be a way to have the image appear more closely to the text? In the example, the width is very narrow, so it doesn't look too terrible. But on wider view ports, the image will always appear on the left side of the container which is less than ideal. Thanks again!

Comment: @JonLeopard hope this edit provides the solution you are looking for!